# Qt Json serialization

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization, qvariant

I have a QVariant which can contain a `double`, a `QString`, a `Foo` object, or anything.

I would like to serialize my `QVariant` without knowing what it contains.
I am trying to do the serialization like this:

```
QJsonObject jsonObject;
jsonObject["myObject"] = _variant.toJsonObject();
```

What function must I overload in `Foo`? Must I use `Q_PROPERTY`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you can do what you want directly. There is no way to convert an arbitrary object like `Foo` to a `QJsonObject` except by manually reading and writing the corresponding fields of the `Foo` object. Since `QVariant` has no way of knowing that your object supports that functionality, you won't be able to use `QVariant` directly. It may help you to follow the example provided by Qt for doing serialization:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

Notice they have manual `read` and `write` methods for the `Game` object.

Comment: The link is broken, it is now: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html#toJsonObject) you should be able to convert any QVariant to QJSonObject

Now your question become : how to transform your Foo class to QVariant ?

I suggest you to add toQVariant and fromQVariant methods to Foo class to encapsulate this behavior ; the most convenient QVariant class is actually QVariantMap that you can use like this to serialize your Foo object

```
QVariant toVariant( Foo song ) {
   QVariantMap map;
   map.insert("album", wstring2Utf8(song.album()));
   map.insert("artist", wstring2Utf8(song.artist()));
   map.insert("duration", song.duration());
   map.insert("fingerprint", wstring2Utf8(song.fingerprint()));
   map.insert("genre", wstring2Utf8(song.genre()));
   map.insert("title", wstring2Utf8(song.title()));
   map.insert("year", song.year());
   return map;
}
```